# C++ defined ?macro? visible in header yet missing in implementation (linker reports unresolved external)

Tags: c++, scope, linker, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some class for specific debug purposes, so I use it only when interested in given functionality

to prevent source rubbish when not needed, I tried to handle it by preprocessor,
so the structure is something like this:

```
===main.cpp===
#define nowUseTmp
#include "tmp.h"
/*normal code which accesses tmp via macros*/
===EOF===

===tmp.h===
#ifdef nowUseTmp
/* class declaration */
/* macros to use static methods on class*/
#else
/*empty macro variants, so they may freely stay in code where needed*/
#endif
===EOF===

===tmp.cpp===
/*EXPECTED PLACE OF PROBLEM*/
#ifdef nowUseTmp
/* definitions */
#endif
===EOF===
```

problem is, that when I enable nowUseTmp (before the_very_first/each include), linker reports unresolved external (like if the macro was defined in header and NOT defined in the cpp file)

**Question:
Why / How / What is better approach**

I expect that cpp files are translated individually, without knowledge of include chain (thus cannot have info about the define)

Is that the case?
If so, how to workaround, so I can have constant "tmp.*" files between multiple projects, and manage enabled/disabled individually per project (i.e. not to use define inside relevant header)

Just to clarify

->when I place "#define tmpUseNow" inside relevant header (tmp.h), all works fine

->relevant header (tmp.h) is included from relevant definition file (tmp.cpp)

->same behavior tested with simplified project with only three files as in example

-> relevant files (tmp.h, tmp.cpp) are assumed constant files shared between many projects (so I do not see how to order them to include predetermined third file with definitions, which would be individual for projects that use them)

Comment: Don't define `nowUseTmp` in your source file but pass it to your compiler, e.g. `-D nowUseTemp` for GCC or add it to your project settings in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each cpp file is processed independently. If I were you, I'd make sure to include tmp.h in tmp.cpp, and I'd only ever define nowUseTmp in tmp.h.

Comment: I accept this one, as that is the way I started using it,
even when I consider @JohanessS. approach little better,
I found myself lazy to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your tmp.cpp functions (name it `use_tmp`) additional parameter with default `value = nowUseTmp` and examine it value for particular behavior:

tmp.h :

```
/* takes par2 value from the define */
void use_tmp(int par1, int par2 = nowUseTmp);
```

tmp.cpp :

```
void use_tmp(int par1, int par2)
{
    if(!par2) /*do smth*/ return;
}
```